# working of annotations in spring

Tags: spring, annotations

Following is Service @interface from Spring

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Service {
    String value() default "";
}
```

It is annoted with @Component. An following is @interface for component

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Component {
}
```

Why @Retention and @Target is given for Service if @Component already have it.Please correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really about Spring but rather Java itself. The annotations placed on annotation `@A` (e.g. `@Target`) won't apply on `@B`, just because `@B` is annotated with `@A`.

---

You can verify this behavior with simple experiment:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface A {}

@A
public @interface B {}

public class Test {
    @B private String foo;
}
```

If `@B` annotation woult get `@Target` from `@A`, then this code would not compile, because `@B` would not be applicable on a field, but it does.